# First order of Taylor polynomial $f(x) =1+3x \int^{x^2}_{2x} e^{-(t)^{1/2}}dt$ around $x=2$?

Tags: calculus

Consider:

$$f(x) =1+3x \int^{x^2}_{2x} e^{-(t)^{1/2}}dt$$

What is the first order of this Taylor polynomial around $x=2$?

I've tried solving it by using the fundamental theorem of calculus, but the problem is I don't know how to solve this one since it has $3x$ in front of the integral.

The answer should be $p(x)=1+12e^{-2}(x-2) $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $3x$ in front of the integral is solved by the product rule:
$$
f'(x) = 0 + 3\int_{2x}^{x^2}e^{-t^{1/2}}dt + 3x\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\int_{2x}^{x^2}e^{-t^{1/2}}dt
$$
where that last part is solved like this:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{2x}^{x^2}e^{-t^{1/2}}dt = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{2x}^{0}e^{-t^{1/2}}dt + \frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x^2}e^{-t^{1/2}}dt\\
= -\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{2x}e^{-t^{1/2}}dt + \frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x^2}e^{-t^{1/2}}dt\\
= -2e^{-(2x)^{1/2}} + 2xe^{-(x^2)^{1/2}}
$$
The last line uses the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus. We therefore have
$$
f'(x) = 3\int_{2x}^{x^2}e^{-t^{1/2}}dt + 3x\left(-2e^{-(2x)^{1/2}} + 2xe^{-(x^2)^{1/2}}\right)
$$
Inserting $x = 2$, we get
$$
f'(2) = 3\int_{4}^{4}e^{-t^{1/2}}dt + 6\left(-2e^{-(4)^{1/2}} + 4e^{-(4)^{1/2}}\right)\\
= 0 + 6\left(-2e^{-2} + 4e^{-2}\right)\\
= 12e^{-2}
$$
In order to find the Taylor approximation of $f$ at $x = 2$ we also need to know $f(2)$, but that is clearly equal to $1$, since the integral limits becomes $\int_4^4$, and therefore the whole integral becomes $0$.

We therefore have $f(2) = 1$ and $f'(2) = 12e^{-2}$, and therefore, the corresponding first-degree Taylor approximation becomes
$$
p(x) = f(2) + f'(2)(x-2) = 1 + 12e^{-2}(x-2)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\big(f(x)\cdot\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}g(x)\ dx\big)' = f(x)\cdot\big[g(b(x))b'(x) - g(a(x))a'(x)\big] + f'(x)\cdot\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}g(x)\ dx$$